# Pass method as parameter in Java to assign Listeners to multiple Buttons

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Java (coming from Python) and I'm trying to pass a method as a parameter in order to convert this code:

```
Button button1;
Button button2;
...
Button buttonN;

button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onClick_button1(v);
    }
});

button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onClick_button2(v);
    }
});

(...)

buttonN = (...)
```

To something like:

```
public AssignListener( integer tButton, Method tMethod )
{
  button_view = (Button) findViewById(tButton);

  button_view.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          tMethod(view);
      }
  }
}

(...)

AssignListener( R.id.button1, onClick_button1 );
AssignListener( R.id.button2, onClick_button2 );
(...)
AssignListener( R.id.buttonN, onClick_buttonN );
```

I've read that you can't pass methods to functions, and some advice to wrap my function using Runnable to achieve this.

I have not clear idea about how to do it. Any idea on how do it easily? :?

Thanks.

EDIT: Should I wrap "AssignListener" in its own class and pass the class itself? :?

Comment: Why don't you just implements OnClickListener.

Comment: When adding a listener in java you pass an object of a class that implements the listener that you're trying to add. (Thus insuring it contains the listener method)

Comment: Thanks Hoan. Yes, I can implement OnClickListener to "solve" this, but the underlying question is how to pass methods to functions. I used the above code as an example of what I try to do...

Comment: I don't think you can pass method in Java. That is why instead of passing the method, say button.setMethod(methodA), you have to pass an implementation of a callback interface which is more or less like an abstract class in C.

Answer (score 2):

You can call findViewById() and seOnClickListener into onCreate method, and OnClickListenet outside the onCreate.

```
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

or

findViewById(R.id.button1).seOnClickListener(mClickListener);
findViewById(R.id.button2).seOnClickListener(mClickListener);
findViewById(R.id.button3).seOnClickListener(mClickListener);
findViewById(R.id.button4).seOnClickListener(mClickListener);

private OnClickListener mClickListener = new View.OnClickListener(
    public void onClick(View view){
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.button1:
            //button1 click handle here...
            break;
            case R.id.button2:
            //button2 click handle here...
            break;
            case R.id.button3:
            //button3 click handle here...
            break;
            case R.id.button4:
            //button4 click handle here...
            break;
        }
    });
```

Try it, hope it will helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that reduces the amount of repeated code (solves part 1, so I will use it in advance). But the underlying question is "how to pass method/function to method as parameter" in my example, and still not sure if it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You could define and pass an onClickListener like this:

```
public AssignListener( integer tButton, OnClickListener listener ){

tButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to create listener implementation for each button, as is written in your first snippet.

I don't see any reasonable benefit of having universal method like AssignListener(). Don't reinvent bicycle, use existing setOnClickListener() method and pass listener specific for button.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. Yes, I could do like in the first snippet (in fact, is like I'm doing it right now) but I always try to keep the code as much smaller and simpler as I can. Writing N times "almost the same code" is candidate to "refactoring" and wrapping it in a single-purpose method/function. That makes the program smaller both in LOC and in size and thus mades easier to find bugs later. Assigning listeners to buttons is not the purpose of the program, so I try to keep to focus in the useful code itself and not to copy-paste 7 lines of code N times for all the buttons I have...

Comment: What you are trying to do is to avoid implementing anonymous Listener class. If you will introduce something like Method interface, you would implement anonymous Method class. So anyway you must implement some class, it's java.

Comment: If you want to hide boilerplate code you can create custom Button class and hide listener initialization in button constructor. For example class Button1, which will add listener1 in it's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to create a function called tMethod that takes a button id, and has a switch statement that allows for a certain action to be performed for the given button id. This would then be called inside the onClick function like  tMethod(view.getId()).

Btw, Python has methods. Java has functions. Pedant mode turned off!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyClass implements OnClickListener, OnLongClickListener {
    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    ...
    Button buttonN;

    . . . 
    setButtonsListener(findViewById(<your top view id>));
    . . .

    void setButtonsListener(ViewGroup vg) {
            int count = vg.getChildCount();
            Button btn;
            View v;
            for(int i=0; i < count ; i++) {
                v = vg.getChildAt(i);
                if( v instanceof Button ) {
                    btn = (Button)v; 
                    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
                    btn.setOnLongClickListener(this);
                } else if( v instanceof ViewGroup ) {
                    setButtonsListener((ViewGroup) v);
                }
            }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```